# What is the "!!" operator in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the !! operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-operator-in-javascript)

Sorry if this one is obvious but I can't google it.

What is the "!!" operator in Javascript? e.g.

```
if (!!window.EventSource) {
  var source = new EventSource('stream.php');
} else {
  // Result to xhr polling :(
}
```

Did the author just use "!" twice i.e. a double negation? I'm confused because this is in the official doc.

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-operator-in-javascript

Comment: Diplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-operator-in-javascript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will convert anything to `true` or `false`:

```
!!0    // => false
!!1    // => true 
!!'a'  // => true
!!''   // => false
!!null // => false
```

Technically, `!!` is not an operator, it is just two `!` operators next to each other. But a double-negation is pointless unless you are using `!!` like an operator to convert to Boolean type.

Comment: +1 Nice answer! A lot clearer than mine.

Comment: @vonconrad: But IMHO your answer is better because one should in the first place explain that there is no such thing as an `!!` operator and only then explain that it is the side-effect of doing negation twice that is wanted.

Comment: @slebetman: Fair point. Still, browsersenior's examples are better than mine. ;)

Answer (score 6):

In most languages, `!!` is double negation, as `!` is negation. Consider this:

```
# We know that...
!false == true

# And therefore...
!!false == false
!!true == true
```

It's often used to check whether a value exists and is not false, as such:

```
!!'some string' == true
!!123 == true
!!myVar == true
```

Answer (score 1):

!! is used to convert a non-zero/non-null value to boolean true and a zero/null value to false.

E.g. if a = 4, then !a = false and !!a = !(!a) = true.